# java async future and concurrency

Tags: java, asynchronous

in a service, we need to batch up calls to new relic logging.  The below code is supposed to send asnc an array of messages when a limit is reached.  However, we are losing messages.  We don't care about the result (although it would be nice to log an error).  In the below code, I would assume that when the monitor protected section is passed, a new caller of send could overwrite the eventArrayCopy in line 3?  I think the developer struggled because the parameter sent to the async call could not be a simple (safe) local variable.

```
    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<HttpResponse<String>> send(JsonElement body)  {
    final JsonArray eventArrayCopy = new JsonArray();

    synchronized (monitor) {
        eventArray.add(body);
        log.info("added event to eventArray. array size:" + eventArray.size());
        if (eventArray.size() < senderConfig.getEventPerRequest() && !isTimeToSend()) 
     {
            return null;
        }
        eventArrayCopy.addAll(eventArray);
        eventArray = new JsonArray();
    }

    
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->sendEvents(eventArrayCopy));
}
```

eventArray is gobal,but is only used inside the monitor.

Comment: `eventArrayCopy` is a function-local variable. Other calls to this function cannot change the value of another function. Where is `eventArray` defined? If this is global, then other threads or calls can modify it.

Comment: eventArray is global, but is only used inside this monitor.

Comment: then why do you need to have it global, if only accessed from this monitor? Get rid of the `eventArray`, get rid of the monitor. Simply `eventArrayCopy = new JsonArray(); eventArrayCopy.add(body); /* rest of method */`.

Comment: And btw: return `null` for a `CompletableFuture` type is generally bad – it forces you to add null checks all over your program. Why not return `CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null)` instead?